# WEB - Hamburger with animation not working in header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Recently i saw a hamburger in Codepen and tried to add it in my web header. When it is placed my header color layout goes mad. Is it possible to place a Hamburger in the header with an animation?
this is what i gave in HTML

```js
$(function() {
  var activateHamburger = function(event) {
    var el = $(this);
    if (el.hasClass('active')) {
      el.addClass('active-end');
      el.one('transitionend', function() {
        el.removeClass('active active-end')
      });
    } else {
      el.addClass('active');
    }
  };
  $('.hamburger').click(activateHamburger);
});
```

```css
      body {
        background-color: #eee;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        line-height: 140%;
        font-size: 0.9em;
      }
      .radial {
        padding: 16px;
      }
      .header {
        height: 200px;
        background: #F44336;
      }
      .inner {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: -170px auto 0 auto;
        padding: 19px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 0.125rem;
        box-shadow: 0 27px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 40px 77px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
      }
      ------------------------------hamburbger-starts-here *,
      *:before,
      *:after {
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      .hamburger {
        *zoom: 1;
      }
      .hamburger:before,
      .hamburger:after {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
      }
      .hamburger:after {
        clear: both;
      }
      .hamburger {
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 20px;
      }
      .hamburger > div {
        background: #03A9F4;
        height: 4px;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .hamburger > div:nth-child(1),
      .hamburger > div:nth-child(3) {
        float: right;
      }
      .hamburger.active {
        -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
        transition: all 0.6s ease;
        -moz-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(180deg) translate(0, 4px);
        -ms-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(180deg) translate(0, 4px);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(180deg) translate(0, 4px);
        transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(180deg) translate(0, 4px);
      }
      .hamburger.active > div {
        -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
        transition: all 0.6s ease;
      }
      .hamburger.active > div:nth-child(1),
      .hamburger.active > div:nth-child(3) {
        width: 70%;
      }
      .hamburger.active > div:nth-child(2) {
        width: 90%;
      }
      .hamburger.active > div:nth-child(1) {
        -moz-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(45deg) translate(2px, 2px);
        -ms-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(45deg) translate(2px, 2px);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(45deg) translate(2px, 2px);
        transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(45deg) translate(2px, 2px);
      }
      .hamburger.active > div:nth-child(3) {
        -moz-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(-45deg) translate(2px, -2px);
        -ms-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(-45deg) translate(2px, -2px);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(-45deg) translate(2px, -2px);
        transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(-45deg) translate(2px, -2px);
      }
      .hamburger.active.active-end {
        -moz-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(360deg) translate(0, 0);
        -ms-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(360deg) translate(0, 0);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(360deg) translate(0, 0);
        transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(360deg) translate(0, 0);
      }
      .hamburger.active.active-end > div {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .hamburger.active.active-end > div:nth-child(1) {
        -moz-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(0deg) translate(0, 0);
        -ms-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(0deg) translate(0, 0);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(0deg) translate(0, 0);
        transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(0deg) translate(0, 0);
      }
      .hamburger.active.active-end > div:nth-child(3) {
        -moz-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(0deg) translate(0, 0);
        -ms-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(0deg) translate(0, 0);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(0deg) translate(0, 0);
        transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(0deg) translate(0, 0);
      }
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="hamburger">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="radial">
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST:</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Test test test test test test test test test test test</li>
      <li>Test test test test test test test test test test test</li>
      <li>Test test test test test test test test test test test</li>
      <li>Test test test test test test test test test test test</li>
      <li>Test test test test test test test test test test test</li>
      <li>Test test test test test test test test test test test</li>
      <li>Test test test test test test test test test test test</li>
      <li>Test test test test test test test test test test test</li>
      <li>Test test test test test test test test test test test</li>
      <li>Test test test test test test test test test test test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check out  [codepen](http://codepen.io/kabadesu/pen/qvdzK) which i tried in my web & Here is my [JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shmshd12/n597t74k/)

Comment: Can you post your code without hamburger to get a reference of what it was before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working perfectly for me, (just added JQuery 1.7.2 and forked).

```
Added JQuery 1.7.2 to the project.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/216201pg/

Comment: You forgot about the color fix :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to add Jquery to your project ;)

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

For the color Fix, add those css properties to your .hamburger class

```
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 12px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n597t74k/4/

Comment: this is just a shameless copy paste of my answer.

Comment: Sry, i was posting when you answered the post :x

Comment: Sounds fair, if yours gets accepted I'm going to be so mad at you though.

Comment: @WorldOfKhriztian What about the header color? before it was full color at top and after inserting HAMBURGER header came down! So, no fix for that?

Comment: @SofieneDJEBALI i tried the code in .hamburger but there was no change so added that css to header and the color was fixed but hamburger came down :(

Comment: what browser are you using bro? @MohammedShamshid. Working perfect in chrome.

Comment: @MohammedShamshid you need to import jQuery, add this line in your html file in your head tag : <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: @SofieneDJEBALI Thanks that worked well :D nooby question : in that hamburger where should i add "href" for my page to go back?

Comment: Your welcome !, don't forget to +1 my answer bro' :)

Comment: @SofieneDJEBALI due to  the content box hamburger is not showing in the mobile version.